# Entity Framework and List<string>.Contains()

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }
}

// MyContext.cs
public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<MyEntity>(
            b =>
            {
                b.ToTable("MyEntities");

                b.HasKey(e => e.Id);

                // Names has column type of "nvarchar(max)"
                b.Property(p => p.Names)
                    .HasConversion(
                        v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, default),
                        v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(v, default));
            });
}
```

In my local SQL database I have this entry:

| Id | Names |
| --- | --- |
| 76B83CBF-0601-4C40-AF92-8B74EBF3AA0E | ["a","b","c"] |

But when I do

```
var found = await context.MyEntities.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Names.Contains("c"));
```

`found` comes back as `null`. How can I fix it so that the entry is returned?

Comment: hi jpen, have you tried to intercept the generated sql query? also, is that `names` column a (n)varchar?

Comment: I think you'll want to use this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions#string-functions
Something like: `await context.MyEntities.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => EF.Functions.Contains(e.Names, "c"))`

Comment: You use a custom serializer/deserializer. The SQL database knows nothing about those. So, in a first step, you have to map the table's entries to objects, and then you can use your methods on the objects. So do something like adding an `AsEnumerable()` to your code: `var found = await context.MyEntities.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Names.Contains("c"));`

Comment: Which EF version? Please use the applicable tag.

Comment: You cannot use properties with conversion in LINQ queries. It is known limitation.